# Do Pages, Numbers and Keynote for Mac/iOS offer real-time collaboration on shared documents like Pages, Numbers and Keynote for iCloud do?

Tags: icloud, pages, keynote, numbers

In Pages and Numbers (I guess Keynote too) for iCloud if you share a document and then send the link to other people you get real-time collaboration between the contributors as they edit the document and you can see the edits taking place live.

Does this work on Pages and Numbers for Mac/iOS?

Comment: Your wait is over - coming in Sierra/iOS 10 :)

Comment: True but I don't think it will be a Sierra/iOS10 exclusive, just a new iWork for mac and ios. http://www.apple.com/apple-events/september-2016/   19min:45sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Real Time Colaboration](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206181) on a computer with at least
iOS 10 and macOS Sierra.